# My answer was upvoted and accepted, but nothing happened with my rep. What can be the reason of that?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, community-wiki

My answer was upvoted and accepted, but nothing happened with my rep. What can be the reason of that? This is my first quesetion on 'meta' and I would not be surprised if this is not the right place to ask it. Sorry for that in advance. But if I am right in this, then where to go? I don't see other possibilities, yet. Maybe you can help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/739286/8348).  Note that due to a significant number of edits, it was automatically made [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/214632), and upvotes and accepts on Community Wiki answers confer no reputation.

Comment: Thank you. This explains everything and is new knowledge to me. In the future I will be more careful with my edits. A good lesson.